# How to define phone number in forms and template error getting:django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: phone_field/phone_widget.html?

Tags: django

How to define phone number field in forms.py and template i tried but getting error:django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: phone_field/phone_widget.html

models.py

```
from phone_field import PhoneField

phone = PhoneField(blank=True, help_text='Contact phone number')
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You may want to read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 13):

I had same problem. The solution worked for me is
by adding `'phone_field'` into `INSTALLED_APPS`.